# org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

I am new to `JSON` and I am getting the follwoing Exception:

`org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject` in the first line of try section itself.

Please help me to remove this. Here's my code:

```
try {   
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(strResponse);

    //Get the element that holds the internship ( JSONArray )
    JSONArray name = json.names();
    JSONArray  internships = json.toJSONArray(name);

    //Loop the Array
    for(int i=0;i < internships.length();i++) {     
        Log.e("Message","loop");
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        JSONObject e = internships.getJSONObject(i);
        map.put("id",  String.valueOf("id"));
        map.put("title", "Title :" + e.getString("title"));
        map.put("company", "Company : " +  e.getString("company"));
        map.put("category", "Category : " +  e.getString("category"));
        mylist.add(map);
    } 
} catch(JSONException e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
}
```

this is the json I am getting from my php file

```
[
 {
    "id": "31",
    "title": "Business Development - Executive",
    "company": "Indidelights",
    "category": "Sales and Business Development"
 },
 {
    "id": "40",
    "title": "Business Development - Ecommerce MH",
    "company": "Ram Gopal & Co",
    "category": "Sales and Business Development"
 },
 {
    "id": "41",
    "title": "Sales and Business development intern",
    "company": "Esanchalak",
    "category": "Sales and Business Development"
 },
 {
    "id": "42",
    "title": "Purchase Executive",
    "company": "Winni.in",
    "category": "Marketing"
 },
 {
    "id": "43",
    "title": "Marketing Intern",
    "company": "Walkover Web Solutions Pvt. Ltd.",
    "category": "Marketing"
 },
 {
    "id": "44",
    "title": "Marketing Intern",
    "company": "SkillKindle Learning Pvt Ltd",
    "category": "Marketing"
 },
 {
    "id": "45",
    "title": "Graphic Designer",
    "company": "Stylopa",
    "category": "Graphic Design / Art Work"
 },
 {
    "id": "46",
    "title": "Graphic Designer",
    "company": "LycondonFX",
    "category": "Graphic Design / Art Work"
 },
 {
    "id": "47",
    "title": "Web Designer",
    "company": "Xapify LLC",
    "category": "Software"
 },
 {
    "id": "48",
    "title": "Web Designer (Frontend)",
    "company": "gotrademark.in",
    "category": "Web Design and Development"
 },
 {
    "id": "49",
    "title": "Content Writing Intern",
    "company": "National Entrepreneurship Network",
    "category": "Content Writing / Journalism"
 },
 {
    "id": "50",
    "title": "Content Writing Intern",
    "company": "Pragmatum Training Pvt Ltd",
    "category": "Content Writing / Journalism"
 },
 {
    "id": "51",
    "title": "HR Intern",
    "company": "GATI Kintetsu Express Pvt Ltd",
    "category": "HR / Recruitment"
 },
 {
    "id": "52",
    "title": "Pharma Intern",
    "company": "Qlinics Health Care Pvt Ltd",
    "category": "BioTechnology / Pharma"
 },
 {
    "id": "53",
    "title": "Android Developer",
    "company": "InoXapps Mobile Solutions Pvt Ltd",
    "category": "Mobile App Development"
 },
 {
    "id": "54",
    "title": "Mobile App developer",
    "company": "RV Media Inc",
    "category": "Mobile App Development"
 },
 {
    "id": "55",
    "title": "Electronics Intern",
    "company": "GA SOFTWARE TECHNOLOGIES PVT LTD",
    "category": "Electronics Engineering"
 }
 ]
```

Comment: Post your full stack trace

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(strResponse);
// your strResponse is a json array
```

should be

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(strResponse);
```

`[` represents json array node

`{` represents json object node

```
for(int i=0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    String id       = jsonobject.getString("id");
    String title    = jsonobject.getString("title");
    String company  = jsonobject.getString("company");
    String category = jsonobject.getString("category");
}
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification,most examples have an object with an array in it but never just the array on its own,but this has cleared things for me thanx

Comment: The constructor JSONObject(int) is undefined?

Comment: This sould be JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(0); insted of  JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(i);

Comment: @TarunVarshney yes that was a typ mistake made. Rectified now.

Comment: Well bust my buttons

Answer (score 6):

You should probably initialize `json` as a `JSONArray`:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(strResponse);
```

Should then be:

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(strResponse);
```

However, that wouldn't work with the following two operations:

```
JSONArray name = json.names(); //.names() doesn't exist in JSONArray
JSONArray  internships = json.toJSONArray(name); // Is instead to be seen as
```

That would be alright if you just alter your loop to get the `JSONObject` from `json` instead (thus removing the dependency towards `.names()`:

```
JSONObject e = json.getJSONObject(i);
```

Edit: Full code

```
try {   
    JSONArray internships = new JSONArray(strResponse);

    //Loop the Array
    for(int i=0;i < internships.length();i++) {     
        Log.e("Message","loop");
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        JSONObject e = internships.getJSONObject(i);
        map.put("id",  String.valueOf("id"));
        map.put("title", "Title :" + e.getString("title"));
        map.put("company", "Company : " +  e.getString("company"));
        map.put("category", "Category : " +  e.getString("category"));
        mylist.add(map);
    } 
} catch(JSONException e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:**

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(strResponse);
```

here, `strResponse` may be in format of `JSONArray` due to which you are getting this exception while converting it into `JSONObject`.

Answer (score 0):

try this one , Your first block is json array so get first json array

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(strResponse);

    for(int i=0;i < jsonarray .length();i++) {
    JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(i);
            map.put("id",   jsonobj .getString("id"));
            map.put("title",  jsonobj .getString("title"));
            map.put("company",  jsonobj .getString("company"));
            map.put("category",  jsonobj .getString("category"));
            mylist.add(map);

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

if that really is the json you are receiving you should replace the entire this:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(strResponse);

//Get the element that holds the internship ( JSONArray )
JSONArray name = json.names();
JSONArray  internships = json.toJSONArray(name);
```

with

```
JSONArray  internships = json.toJSONArray(strResponse);
```

Comment: @lvo hi i have same problem ....can u tell me how u get the values of strResponse.........