# Android org.json.jsonarray cannot be converted to jsonobject error

Tags: java, android, json, api

I'm new in JSON, but I try to use all answers and didn't work. Help please, what I doing wrong.

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        editText.setText(s);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
            JSONArray resultArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("query");

            addresses = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i<resultArray.length(); i++){
               addresses.add(resultArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Name"));
                Log.d("DTA",resultArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Name"));

            }
            refreshAdapter();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

It's my JSON for parsing.

```
{  
  "query":{  
    "count":2,
    "created":"2016-10-04T19:50:08Z",
    "lang":"ru",
    "results":{  
      "rate":[  
        {  
          "id":"USDRUB",
          "Name":"USD/RUB",
          "Rate":"62.8240",
          "Date":"10/4/2016",
          "Time":"7:21pm",
          "Ask":"62.8416",
          "Bid":"62.8240"
        },
        {  
          "id":"EURRUB",
          "Name":"EUR/RUB",
          "Rate":"70.3460",
          "Date":"10/4/2016",
          "Time":"7:21pm",
          "Ask":"70.3740",
          "Bid":"70.3460"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441246/org-json-jsonarray-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject?rq=1

Comment: Can you post some more detail on the error? Some logs, maybe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: 10-05 07:30:01.604 11310-11310/com.harbinger.currency W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"count":2,"created":"2016-10-05T04:30:00Z","lang":"en-US","results":{"rate":[{"id":"USDRUB","Name":"USD\/RUB","Rate":"62.6486","Date":"10\/5\/2016","Time":"0:57am","Ask":"62.7480","Bid":"62.6486"},{"id":"EURRUB","Name":"EUR\/RUB","Rate":"70.2230","Date":"10\/5\/2016","Time":"0:57am","Ask":"70.3570","Bid":"70.2230"}]}} at query of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Answer (score 0):

That's because `query` is not an array, it is an object. I guess you want to get the objects from `rate`, this is how to do it:

```
 try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
        JSONObject resultsObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("results");
        JSONArray resultArray = resultsObject.getJSONArray("rate");
        ... etc... now iterate
```

Comment: 10-05 07:42:54.532 15781-15781/com.harbinger.currency W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for results

Comment: try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONObject resultsObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("results");
                JSONArray resultArray = resultsObject.getJSONArray("rate");

                addresses = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i<resultArray.length(); i++){
                   addresses.add(resultArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Name"));
                    Log.d("DTA",resultArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Name"));

                }

Comment: It's not working. Studio don't see any values for results :(