# Error 'JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject' in Android

Tags: java, android, json

I am new to `JSON` and I have been referring to some youtube videos for the question given in the link [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441246/org-json-jsonarray-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject) on how to handle the error but I still don't understand why I am getting the same error.

The error log are as following:

```
2021-01-12 10:30:10.327 30666-315/... W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"lastUpdateTs":1610342055312,"key":"capacity","value":20},{"lastUpdateTs":1610342069003,"key":"free","value":4},{"lastUpdateTs":1610342055324,"key":"capacity","value":20},{"lastUpdateTs":1610342070857,"key":"free","value":4}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
2021-01-12 10:30:10.327 30666-315/... W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:112)
2021-01-12 10:30:10.328 30666-315/... W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:168)
2021-01-12 10:30:10.328 30666-315/... W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:181)
2021-01-12 10:30:10.328 30666-315/... W/System.err:     at ...PremisesListTaskLoader.loadInBackground(PremisesListTaskLoader.java:118)
2021-01-12 10:30:10.328 30666-315/... W/System.err:     at ....PremisesListTaskLoader.loadInBackground(PremisesListTaskLoader.java:20)
2021-01-12 10:30:10.328 30666-315/... W/System.err:     at androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:307)
2021-01-12 10:30:10.328 30666-315/... W/System.err:     at androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:60)
2021-01-12 10:30:10.328 30666-315/... W/System.err:     at androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:48)
2021-01-12 10:30:10.328 30666-315/... W/System.err:     at androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:141)
2021-01-12 10:30:10.328 30666-315/... W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2021-01-12 10:30:10.328 30666-315/... W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2021-01-12 10:30:10.328 30666-315/... W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2021-01-12 10:30:10.328 30666-315/... W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

here's my code:

```
try {      
      if (code2 / 100 == 2) {
            BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection2.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
            String input2;
            while ((input2 = reader2.readLine()) != null) {
                  sb2.append(input2);
            }
            reader2.close();

            JSONObject response2 = new JSONObject(sb2.toString());  // <- The line mentioned   at ...PremisesListTaskLoader.loadInBackground(PremisesListTaskLoader.java:118)
            JSONArray data2 = response2.getJSONArray("data");
            int length2 = data2.length();

            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < length2; i2++) {
                  JSONObject object2 = data2.getJSONObject(i2);
                  String deviceType = object2.getString("key");
                  String deviceId = object2.getString("value");
            }
    }
      connection2.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The data that I want to retrieve (which are stored in `input2`) are as following:

```
[
  {
    "lastUpdateTs": 1604651123669,
    "key": "capacity",
    "value": 20
  },
  {
    "lastUpdateTs": 1606467758647,
    "key": "free",
    "value": 12
  }
]
```

Comment: Please learn JSON. `[ ]` is a JSON array, so why do you believe that parsing it as a JSON object would work? Since the root is an array, change `new JSONObject(sb2.toString())` to `new JSONArray(sb2.toString())`.

Answer (score 1):

```
[
  {
    "lastUpdateTs": 1604651123669,
    "key": "capacity",
    "value": 20
  },
  {
    "lastUpdateTs": 1606467758647,
    "key": "free",
    "value": 12
  }
]
```

This is JSONArray format cause could not convert by `JSONObject response2 = new JSONObject(sb2.toString());`

Replace:

```
JSONObject response2 = new JSONObject(sb2.toString());  
JSONArray data2 = response2.getJSONArray("data");
int length2 = data2.length();

for (int i2 = 0; i2 < length2; i2++) {
   JSONObject object2 = data2.getJSONObject(i2);
   String deviceType = object2.getString("key");
   String deviceId = object2.getString("value");
}
```

With:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(sb2.toString());  
for (int i2 = 0; i2 < jsonArray.length(); i2++) {
   JSONObject object2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i2);
   String deviceType = object2.getString("key");
   String deviceId = object2.getInt("value");
}
```